# Jquery animate scrolltop not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm using this code to navigate to anchors on the same page, with a smooth scrolling effect. It works great in all browsers except in Safari 6.

I've done some testing and this works in Safari 5/6, Chrome, and Firefox, removing the animate scroll:

```
$(document).on('click','.navigation a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
    var position = $target.data('position');
    $('html, body').scrollTop( position * scrollHeight );
});
```

But with the animate scroll, it stops working in Safari 6:

```
$(document).on('click','.navigation a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
    var position = $target.data('position');
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop': position * scrollHeight}, 3000);
});
```

Any ideas as to why and how to fix?

Comment: try https://github.com/JamyGolden/PlusAnchor its really nice

Comment: I tried this and I'm not sure if it's conflicting with other js on my page but I can't get it to work.

Comment: does anyone know why this is causing an issue or how to fix in Safari 6?